Did Northern Exposure influence Ballykissangel?
Is there any acknowledged or widely recognized influence on Ballykisangel (1996-2001) from Northern Exposure (1990-1995)?
Admittedly none of these are super unique ideas, but there are a lot of parallels between the shows. Obviously to start off they're both "quirky dramadies", with occasional magical-realist moments.
Both shows center on an outsider (Dr. Fleischmann / Father Clifford) assigned to a culturally isolated village (Cicely, Alaska / Ballykissangel, Ireland) with beautiful scenery. The MC develops a bickering romantic tension with a local (Maggie / Assumpta) who becomes the MC's landlord. The townsfolk congregate in the local bar/pub (Holling's / Fitzgerald's) and the town is economically dominated by the one rich guy (Maurice / Brian) who is constantly coming up with hare-brained schemes to increase his wealth, including building a golf course.
Again, none of those are things that have never been done before, and there are other character types in either show who aren't in the other, but there's a pretty strong pattern of similarities here.

The shows are astoundingly similar. I've seen Ballykissangel described as "The BBCs answer to Northern Exposure" on multiple websites.

@Valorum, adding that quote with a source would improve your answer.

The opinions of critics don't really interest me.

@Valorum, OK but they are part of what I asked about when I asked about "widely recognized" influences. Your answer is helpful because it addresses acknowledged influences, but it would be improved by also addressing influences recognized by knowledgeable critics or commentators.

This is the sort of thing I'm referring to. Not exactly authoritative; "The BBC's answer to Northern Exposure comes in the form of this comedy/drama series set in a tiny Irish village whose new Catholic priest is a young, naive Englishman." - https://www.eskimo.com/~rkj/b.htm

Probably not.

Q. "What gave you the idea for Ballykissangel?"
Kieran [Kieran Prendiville]: A few years ago I spent several weeks on an oil rig researching a drama series called Roughnecks. After a while I went stir crazy and started fantasising about a place where you didn’t hear the thud and clatter of heavy machinery twenty four hours a day ... and where it didn’t smell of diesel oil.
Then I remembered the holidays in Ireland I took when I was kid, when my father took all eight of us back to this tiny village in County Kerry where he was from ... and then I remembered some of the characters ...and then I was off and running.
I had to put it aside for a few years while I wrote Roughnecks; I didn’t honestly think anyone would be interested but there you are.
By the way, the village - it’s a town now - was called Killorglin. Just up the road there’s a real place called Ballykissane.
BBC Online - Interview of the Week

